# Trouble with Swift Protocols, associatedtypes, Self and default implementations

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, associated-types, default-implementation

I am trying to get some functionality through default implementations that I can't nail. Consider the following code, which is a simplification of what I'm trying to do, but captures the problem as simply as possible.

```
//protocol definition
protocol Configurable {
    associatedtype Data
    func configure(data: Data)

    static func generateObject() -> Self
}

//default implementation for any UIView
extension Configurable where Self: UIView {
    static func generateObject() -> Self {
        return Self()
    }
}

//implement protocol for UILabels
extension UILabel: Configurable {
    typealias Data = Int

    func configure(data: Int) {
        label.text = "\(data)"
    }
}

//use the protocol
let label = UILabel.generateObject()
label.configure(data: 5)
print(label.text!)  //5
```

I have a protocol, a default implementation for some methods for UIView, and the a specific implementation for UILabel.

My issue is the last part... the actual use of all this functionality

```
let label = UILabel.generateObject()
label.configure(data: 5)
print(label.text!)  //5
```

I find myself doing `generateObject()` followed by `configure(data: <something>)` constantly. So I tried doing the following:

Add `static func generateObjectAndConfigure(data: Data) -> Self` to the protocol. The issue comes when I try to make a default implementation for UIView for this method. I get the following error

`Method 'generateObjectAndConfigure(data:)' in non-final class 'UILabel' cannot be implemented in a protocol extension because it returns`Self`and has associated type requirements`

Basically, I can't have a method that returns `Self` and uses an associated type. It feels really nasty for me to always call the two methods in a row. I want to only declare `configure(Data)` for each class and get `generateObjectAndConfigure(Data)` for free.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that your default implementation will crash for some classes, e.g. `UICollectionView`. Also using `Self()` kinda abuses the fact that the no-param initializer is still available `UIView`'s, even if for many of subclasses it doesn't make sense to call it. Better keep those two separated: instantiation and configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this a bit, by using `Self`.

All you need to do is declare an initialiser in your `Configurable` protocol that accepts your `Data` `associatedtype` as an argument, and has a non-static configure function:

```
protocol Configurable {
    associatedtype Data
    init(data: Data)
    func configure(data: Data)
}
```

Provide a default implementation of that initializer in an extension for the `Configurable` protocol (for `UIView` and its subclasses):

```
extension Configurable where Self: UIView {
    init(data: Data) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.configure(data: data)
    }
}
```

Finally, add conformance to the protocol via an extension to any `UIView` subclasses you're interested in. All you need to do here is to implement the `typealias` and `configure` method:

```
extension UILabel: Configurable {
typealias Data = Int
func configure(data: Data) {
    text = "\(data)"
}
```

}

```
extension UIImageView: Configurable {
    typealias Data = String
    func configure(data: Data) {
        image = UIImage(named: data)
    }
}
```

This implementation has the added bonus that you're using an initializer to create your views (the standard Swift pattern for instantiating an object), rather than a static method:

```
let label = UILabel(data: 10)
let imageView = UIImageView(data: "screenshot")
```

It's not exactly clear to me why the compiler doesn't like your version. I would have thought that subclasses of `UILabel` would inherit the `typealias` meaning that the compiler shouldn't have a problem inferring both `Self` and `Data`, but apparently this isn't supported yet.

Edit: @Cristik makes a good point about `UICollectionView` in the comments.

This problem can be solved by adding a protocol extension for `Configurable` where the `Self` is `UICollectionView`, using the appropriate initializer:

```
extension Configurable where Self: UICollectionView {
    init(data: Data) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.configure(data: data)
    }
}
```

Then, when adding conformance to `Configurable` for `UICollectionView`, we make the `Data` `typealias` a `UICollectionViewLayout`:

```
extension UICollectionView: Configurable {
    typealias Data = UICollectionViewLayout
    func configure(data: Data) {
        collectionViewLayout = data
    }
}
```

Personally, I think this is a reasonable approach for classes where the `init(frame:)` initializer isn't appropriate.

Comment: "You're overcomplicating this a bit"...

Omg yes! Your init() approach works perfectly! Thank you!